# Thermistor doesn't work

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, c++, temperature-sensor

Connecting all like shows the image, thermistor shows, that I'm going to be burnt:

[image]
[image]
The code is simple:

```
#define analogPin  A0 //the thermistor attach to 
#define beta 4090 
#define resistance 10 

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  //read thermistor value 
  long a =analogRead(analogPin);
  //the calculating formula of temperature
  float tempC = beta /(log((1025.0 * 10 / a - 10) / 10) + beta / 298.0) - 273.0;
  float tempF = 1.8*tempC + 32.0;
  Serial.print("Temp: ");

  Serial.print(tempC);

  Serial.print("  C");

  Serial.print("Fahr: ");
  Serial.print(tempF);
  Serial.print(" F");
  delay(200); //wait for 100 milliseconds
}
```

Do I have a wrong thermistor or wrong code?

Comment: There are no magicians here. What model/type of thermistor have you connected? What the thermistor's parameters are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series resistance is 220 Ohms (Red, Red, Brown).

You also need to take into account the thermistor resistance at 25C. Assuming its 10K. Hence choosing a 10K series resistance will make the calculations easier.

```
     int THERMISTORNOMINAL =  10000;
     int SERIESRESISTOR = 10000;
     int TEMPERATURENOMINAL = 25;  

     a = 1023 / a - 1;
     a = SERIESRESISTOR / a;
     tempC = a / THERMISTORNOMINAL;     // (R/Ro)
     tempC = log(tempC);                  // ln(R/Ro)
     tempC /= Beta;                   // 1/B * ln(R/Ro)
     tempC += 1.0 / (TEMPERATURENOMINAL + 273.15); // + (1/To)
     tempC = 1.0 / steinhart;                 // Invert
     tempC -= 273.15;                         // convert to C
```

Comment: Could you make a full working sketch? This code snippet is confusing because it does not show if the variables are a float or integer. Add a link to a source for your calculation as well.

Comment: I used 10K. The image is wrong.